# Is something wrong with My Python 3.3.2?

Tags: python

When using Python 3.3.2 shell

```
>>> temperature = 70
>>> if temperature > 60 and temperature < 75:
    print ("Just right!!")
    else:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

what am I doing wrong?? This happen ever time after I type "else:" and press enter. Im stuck

Comment: By the way, did you know you can also write `if 60 < temperature < 75:`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to indent your code properly:

```
>>> temperature = 70
>>> if temperature > 60 and temperature < 75:
...     print('Just right!')
... else:
...     print('Oh no!')
...
Just right!
```

*When you indent it properly the `...` will automatically show up (so don't type those in).*

Unlike most languages, in Python indentation is important. It is how the Python interpreter indentifies *blocks of code*. You might hear the phrase "whitespace is significant", it means the same thing. whitespace means things you type that don't print (like spaces, the tab character, etc).

So you should always line up the identifier of blocks of code (lines that end with `:`) at the left margin.  It is not important how many spaces you indent the body of these blocks of code (in your example, the print function is in the body of the if statement). As long as there is one space, Python will work. However, the standard is to use 4 spaces; so better get into the habit putting four spaces whenever you want to indent code.

Answer (score 4):

The `else:` statement needs to be at the same level of indentation as the `if:` statement that it refers to.

```
>>> temperature = 70
>>> if temperature > 60 and temperature < 75:
...    print ("Just right!!")
... else:
...    print ("Oh noes.")
...
Just right!!
```

This is correct behaviour - otherwise Python wouldn't know what an `else:` statement is referring to:

```
>>> if True:
...    if False:
...        print("Wha?")
...    else:
...        print("Yay.")
... else:
...     print("Huh?")
...
Yay.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need "else" after your condition. You might need it if you want to print additional info if first condition is not met

```
temperature = 70
if temperature > 60 and temperature < 75:
    print("Just right!!")
```

Comment: He obviously needs the `else`, but he's prevented from entering its clause by the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker obviously? I don't find it obvious - he doesn't tell anything about what should happen afterwards. Nevertheless, the answer should read "You don't seem to need `else`...".

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you don't need the `else` statement if you don't want to do anything with the else case.

But, if you want to have an `else` statement but doesn't want to do anything, you can put `pass` statement:

```
>>> temperature = 70
>>> if 60 < temperature < 75:
...     print ("Just right!!")
... else:
...     pass
...
Just right!!
>>>
```